# How can I use chrome black box content script when I debug?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js opens up in the sources window and effectively prevents me from using devtools

I have checked blackbox content script in chrome settings,but it doesn't work.
I know it maybe about the extension "lastpass"

Comment: I suggest enabling LastPass extension only when you actually need it and disable it immediately. It needlessly injects a ton of code with MutationObservers and such into every page instead of doing it on-demand.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thx ! That means I should use incognito window to debug?

Comment: @jackpetton yes, incognito window is a good solution.